# Merge columns with empty values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns of data `name1` and `name2`. I need to merge these columns but they are arranged like this:

```
name1 | name2
1       empty
empty   2
3       empty
empty   4
```

Here empty means a blank space in the table.

I need the output to be like this

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Please give an example table (in text, not an image) and the result you would expect from that sample table

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a simple `NVL`

```sql
WITH
    sample_data (name1, name2)
    AS
        (SELECT 1, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL, 2 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT NULL, 4 FROM DUAL)
SELECT nvl(name1, name2) as names
  FROM sample_data;
```